# Not allowed to launch cutom protocol because a user gesture is required

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, gesture, custom-protocol

I need to run my custom protocol twice but it doesn't work the second time, I got this error ( **Not allowed to launch 'cutomProtocol' because user gesture is required.** ) I tried to find a solution but I did not find any!

Same problem with chrome, firefox and edge.

[image]

I need to see this popup twice
[image]

`window.location.href = 'my-protocol://${base64}';`

and

```
customProtocolVerify(
      `my-protocol://${base64}`,
      () => {
        // successCb: Callback function which gets called when custom protocol is found.
        console.log('My protocol found and opened the file successfully..');
      },
      () => {
        // failCb: Callback function which gets called when custom protocol not found.
        console.log('My protocol not found.');
      }
    );
```

I tried with these two and didn't work

**Clarification**

I have a custom protocol.

My scenario:

1. check if it's installed successfully (I'm using `customProtocolVerify` method) and that method makes the launch if the protocol is found
2. run some APIs
3. launch the protocol again

My problem:

Step 3 doesn't work, I have the error on the console that says " Not allowed to launch... " and of course I can't see my popup to open my protocol.

I'm asking for help to make step 3 work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same issue, even though I have individual click events only opening a single URI

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. first time it launches successfully but second time blocked.

Comment: I found this article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/not-allowed-to-launch-lt-external-protocol-gt-because-a-user/m-p/3371418 that says this is bug in chromium

Comment: here is bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1096610

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please also note that Stack Overflow is an English-only site; providing images of dialogs in another language is of little use.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to bypass this "bug" is to ask the user twice (or in a loop) by showing a OK alert or some sort of user confirm box.

My solution:

```
OpenLinkInExternalApp(Link);
alerty.alert('', { title: '', okLabel: 'Open Link'  }, function () {
    OpenLinkInExternalApp(Link);
});
```

The above code will open the external app, then a OK alert will pop up, after clicking OK, I call the same code again.  Do this in a loop if needed.

TIP:
We guide our users to use split screen at this stage. This is where users can dock your web-app on the left and the external app on the right as an example.

Alert Box:
We user Alerty.js https://github.com/undead25/alerty#readme